# IIS hosted WCF service doesn't load

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF Service, I try debugging it with a browser using IIS Express (start from Visual Studio). I get a message:

**The type 'MyService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found**

I am pretty sure that the service name matches what is in the MyService.svc, I suspect that some of the assemblies I refer to in my service project have other references that need to be included. Is there any way to get more information about what causes the problem? FusionLog doesn't show anything, I tried to check with procmon.exe what is happening in iisexpress.exe process, which dll's cannot be loaded, etc - but no luck. Enabling tracing doesn't help either...

Comment: Did you convert your wcf to application in IIS?

Comment: Also check [that](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/611706/system-serviceModel-serviceHos)

Comment: I use IISExpress, it is started from Visual Studio, worked fine before...

Comment: Did you change service class name and forgot to change it in .svc file? Open .svc file and check markup if service class name is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: So far I tracked that changing the build output to something else than projecdir/bin causes the problem, when I change output to projectdir/bin  everything works fine...

Comment: @Myar your service will work fine when run from Visual Studio because it is self-hosting it but, as Orkun Bekar pointed out, you need to convert it to an application after you deploy it to your inetpub\wwwroot\.... folder, you can do this using INETMGR (run from the start menu). Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, the problem was that the service wasn't activated from Visual Studio...